# How can I get this array data from inside a function returned to me javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, scope

I created a promise that first runs a function to gather data and push it to an initially empty array.

I have tried passing in a global empty array variable, along with minor line changes here and there, however the best I could get was **undefined** or **nothing**.

Is it possible or am I wasting my time?

```js
router.get('/api/fetch', (err, res) => {
  let results = [];
  // finding all and displaying topic and title, which is the 2nd param
  let promiseInfo = () => {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        grabArticles(results);
        resolve();
      });
  };

  promiseInfo().then(() => {
      //there is nothing that shows here, empty array
      console.log(results);
      res.send({results: results});
  });
});
```

```js
// function that uses cheerio npm
grabArticles = (results) => {
  results = [];
  console.log('this is passed data: ' + results);
  request("https://fivethirtyeight.com/", function(error, response, html) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    for (x=1; x<4; x++) {
      // i is the current loop number, element=this is the current data requested
      $('#home-feature-' + x.toString()).each((i, element) => {
        const topic = $(element).children('.post-info').children('.topic').text().trim();
        const title = $(element).children('.post-info').children('.tease-meta').children('.tease-meta-content').children('h2.article-title.entry-title').text().trim();

        const newArticle = {
          topic: topic,
          title: title
        };

        // newArticle.save();
        results.push(newArticle);
      })
    }
    
    //this console.log, has results = 3 objects inside of a results array
    console.log(results);
    return results;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Promise`.

> The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

As the doc explains Promise represents future value, therefore you need to chaine your code to the "same future".

You can achieve that via calling `resolve` function with the value, then that value will be available for you on the "next" `then`.

Something like that:

```
router.get('/api/fetch', (err, res) => {
  let results = [];
  // finding all and displaying topic and title, which is the 2nd param
  let promiseInfo = () => {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(grabArticles(results));
        // --------------^
      });
  };

  promiseInfo().then((results) => {
  // -------------------^
      //there is nothing that shows here, empty array
      console.log(results);
      res.send({results: results});
  });
});
```

Comment: hello thanks for clearing up the promise, however I still getting a console.log(results) = undefined in the .then function

Comment: Check if your `grabArticles` is getting the data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because of the way you are using the promise:

```
grabArticles(results);
resolve();
```

Above, `grabArticles` is asynchronous, so while it is still being run, `resolve` is executed. So you resolve the promise but have not yet completed the asynchronous work.

See example below:

```js
router.get('/api/fetch', (err, res) => {
  // finding all and displaying topic and title, which is the 2nd param
  let promiseInfo = () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      request("https://fivethirtyeight.com/", function(error, response, html) {
        let results = [];
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        for (x = 1; x < 4; x++) {
          // i is the current loop number, element=this is the current data requested
          $('#home-feature-' + x.toString()).each((i, element) => {
            const topic = $(element).children('.post-info').children('.topic').text().trim();
            const title = $(element).children('.post-info').children('.tease-meta').children('.tease-meta-content').children('h2.article-title.entry-title').text().trim();

            const newArticle = {
              topic: topic,
              title: title
            };

            // newArticle.save();
            results.push(newArticle);
          })
        }

        //this console.log, has results = 3 objects inside of a results array
        console.log(results);
        return resolve(results);
      });
    });
  };

  promiseInfo().then(results => {
    //there is nothing that shows here, empty array
    console.log(results);
    res.send({
      results: results
    });
  });
});
```